# Is there a good way to tag files and directories?

Tags: search, tag

I have files and directories stored in multiple ways, some at my home directory, some in Dropbox and some in TrueCrypt volume files. I would like to be able to add tags to files and directories such that they can then be searched for using the tags as search parameters.

## example 1

I have files (photographs, videos and sound recordings) from a digital camera and I have photographs from a mobile telephone. Using this hypothetical program, I have tagged all of these files (say with "Montreux" and "2015"). I should be able to search for all of these files using the mentioned tags as search parameters and be presented with a virtual directory listing of all of the files.

## example 2

I have two directories associated with a project (say, tagged with "Hercolubus"). One directory is at my home directory and the other is in an encrypted TrueCrypt volume file. When I search for everything tagged as "Hercolubus" I am presented with solely the directory at my home directory. When I mount the TrueCrypt volume and search again, I am presented with both the directory at my home directory and the directory in the mounted TrueCrypt volume in a virtual directory listing.

Is there some robust way to accomplish this type of thing? How should tags be stored? Is there a way to ensure that it can cope with the movement of files and directories?

Comment: Apparently Nautilus (the version from `gnome-team`'s PPA?) has an extension for tagging.

Comment: you could try `dtags`found at `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dtags`